# How to use NodePort with kind?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, port, kind

I'm trying to use [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) with [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) but somehow it doesn't want to work.

I've successfully deployed the following cluster:

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 30000
    listenAddress: "0.0.0.0" # Optional, defaults to "0.0.0.0"
    protocol: tcp # Optional, defaults to tcp
- role: worker
```

and then a very simple deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hostname-deployment
  labels:
    app: hostname
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hostname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hostname
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hostname
        image: hostname:0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hostname-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hostname
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

and I can connect to the service via e.g.

```
(in one terminal)
k port-forward service/hostname-service 8080:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80

(another one)
curl localhost:8080
hostname: hostname-deployment-75c9fd6584-ddc59 at Wed, 17 Jun 2020 15:38:33 UTC
```

But I cannot connect to the service via the exposed NodePort

```
curl -v localhost:30000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:30000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 30000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:30000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

---

`kubectl get all` output:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hostname-deployment-75c9fd6584-ddc59   1/1     Running   0          34m
pod/hostname-deployment-75c9fd6584-tg8db   1/1     Running   0          34m

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/hostname-service   NodePort    10.107.104.231   <none>        80:30000/TCP   34m
service/kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        35m

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hostname-deployment   2/2     2            2           34m

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hostname-deployment-75c9fd6584   2         2         2       34m
```

Comment: are you on Mac?

Comment: That's on Linux

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Kind cluster configuration needs to be like below

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30000
    hostPort: 30000
    listenAddress: "0.0.0.0" # Optional, defaults to "0.0.0.0"
    protocol: tcp # Optional, defaults to tcp
- role: worker
```

This file is then passed to your creation command as `kind create cluster --config=config.yaml` ([according to docs](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/)).

Comment: I did not try but would like to know if in this case, only one port 30000 works or multiple services with different ports work?

Comment: Then set the 30000 port as nodePort in NodePort service. Service should be available at localhost:30000, unfortunately for me it was very unstable (kind thing?), sometimes working but mostly failing.

Comment: In my case, i had to add this mapping in order to access a service of a cluster running within GitLab CI/DinD.

Answer (score 5):

Actually doing what [Arghya Sadhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839482/arghya-sadhu) suggested worked. Not sure why the answer got deleted.

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30000
    hostPort: 30000
    listenAddress: "0.0.0.0"
    protocol: tcp
- role: worker
```

Comment: Glad it worked..I was not sure so asked if you are on mac..I have undeleted my answer..

Comment: So it's just the `containerPort: 30000` setting what was wrong? And after that `localhost:30000` worked? Because I am still having problems

Comment: @MichaelLossagk were you able to figure this out?

Comment: It is working even on a Mac, please delete the Kind Cluster first then re-create. I was able to get it working this way. Make sure the NodePort is mapped to the same container port.

Answer (score 4):

I will share my answer as i tried out this today by using multi node kind cluster and another important thing is that needs to take care about kubectl client and server versions. I believe this will help someone.

Step 1

kind-api-cluster.yml

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30950
    hostPort: 30950
    listenAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    protocol: TCP
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

Step 2
Kubernetes service and deployment file. ( If you note here, the kind's control-plane hostPort and kubernetes service's nodePort should be the same )

api.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: api
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      nodePort: 30950
      targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
```

Additional Notes:-

kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.4-dirty", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2021-03-15T09:55:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-21T01:11:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

kind --version

```
kind version 0.10.0
```

Comment: hostPort and containerport value of 30000 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use nodeport with local IP.
Instead you should:

1. use command : kubectl get nodes -o wide
2. note down the IP of the node
3. curl :30000

or

2. docker exec -it  /bin/bash
3. curl localhost:30000

Comment: u are right however, the kind clusters don't expose external node ips

Comment: @user2083529 In you machine, it is if you use extraPortMappings of kind config. If you use aws ec2, you can even use aws ec2 public IP to access it. https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#:~:text=Extra%20port%20mappings%20can%20be,ll%20want%20to%20use%20these.

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl port-forward svc/hostname-service 30000:80
```

Now your service will be accessed on host port 30000

Answer (score 3):

in the kind config yaml

**containerPort** must be the  same with the 'NodePort' in service config.
in your case is 30000

tips: **hostPort** can be any port ,it does not need to be the same with **containerPort**

Answer (score 2):

I got it worked by two options:

1. Either you keep the same nodePort config while creating the service and the one used to create the kind cluster.
2. The second is to keep any nodePort in the service manifest just use the port forward command

kubectl port-forward svc/hostname-service [assigned node port to service]:80

Then access it using localhost:[nodePort]

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the nodePort: 30000 and check that the newly assigned nodePort works with the loopback interface. If you do an update of the service, kube has a problem with satically asigned nodePorts, you have to manige yourself the port collision. Trying to delete the deployment and redeploy could also help.