# Kubernetes local using kind, can't reach service

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I am following a very simple tutorial where it spawns a simple pod with an http endpoint and a service to expose that app using kubernetes.

The setup is very simple:

app-pod.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-pod
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web-ctr
      image: nigelpoulton/getting-started-k8s:1.0
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

And the nodeport service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ps-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 31111
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: web
```

The service and pod seem to be healthy:

[image]

But I can't reach the running app:

`locahost:31111`

Give " This site can't be reached message"

I am new to this stuff so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubernetes Kind cluster, by default, `NodePort` may not be bound to `localhost`. Please check the following resources:

- https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#mapping-ports-to-the-host-machine
- [How to use NodePort with kind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432961/how-to-use-nodeport-with-kind)

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I created this gist with a quick start so others can quickly start instead of going around all the BS complexity around -> https://gist.github.com/mmaia/ff49117b110702a314aabd5b294cc951

Comment: Nice, happy that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to access the service from localhost (like you are trying to do) would be to use

```
kubectl port-forward
```

e.g. the following command would work in your case - which forwards traffic from localhost -> ps-nodeport service

```
kubectl port-forward service/ps-nodeport 31111: 31111
```